Using superscript for ‘grouped by’ variable with gt()
I am trying to add superscript (units) for each level of a variable in a gt() table. I’m able to do it easily for columns using cols_units() however it isn’t applying to the column that is being grouped by.
I tried using html script as seen in this post, however that also seems to apply to cols_label, and not the grouped by variable.
https://forum.posit.co/t/superscripts-subscripts-in-gt-column-labels/44088
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
